# Prove that a finite solvable $T_{nsp}$-group is supersolvable

Tags: group-theory

Definition: 
A subgroup $H$ Of a finite group $G$ is called nearly S-permutable in $G$ if for each prime $p$ with $(p,|H|)=1$ and for every subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing $H$ the normalizer $N_K(H)$ contains some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$.

A finite group is called $T_{nsp}$-group if nearly S-permutiability is transitive in the group.

> Problem: Prove that a finite solvable $T_{nsp}$-group is supersolvable.

The only ref I found on the internet is [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239798240_On_Nearly_S-Permutable_Subgroups_of_Finite_Groups).

Please help.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Do you mean $T_nsp$ or $T_{nsp}$? The $\LaTeX$ code for the latter is `$T_{nsp}$`.

Comment: Yes I meant a solvable $T_{nsp}$-group is supersolvable.

Comment: The group $C_3\times S_3 $ is an example where a factor group of nearly S-permutable is NOT nearly S-permutable.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea if you wrote down exactly what you mean by "S-permutability is transitive in the group". And in your comment, what does "factor group of nearly S-permutable" mean?

Comment: Definition: a finite group G is called $T_{nsp}$ group if for any subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $G$, such that,  $A$ nearly S-permutable in $B$, and $B$ is nearly S-permutable in $G$ implies $A$  nearly S-permutable in $G$.

Comment: Remark: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and if $A$ is another subgroup of $G$ cnotaining $N$ such that $A$ is nearly S-permutable in $G$ Then $A/N$ need not be nearly S-permutable in $G/N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group that is not supersolvable. We need to prove that $G$ is not $T_{\rm nsp}$.

Since $G$ is not supersolvable, it has a chief factor $M/N$ which is elementary abelian or order $p^k$ for some prime $p$ and $k>1$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$. By the Frattini Argument, $G = NN_G(P)$, so we can assume that $N_G(P) = G$ i.e. $P \unlhd G$.

Choose a $p$-subgroup $L$ with $P \cap N < L < P$ such that $L/N$ is central in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. We will prove that $L$ is not S-permutable in $G$ which, since $L$ is S-permutable in $P$, and $P$ is S-permutable in $G$, will contradict transitivity of S-permutability.

Since $M/N$ is a chief factor of $G$, $L$ cannot be normal in $G$ so, since $N_G(L)$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, there must be a prime $q \ne p$ and $q$-element $g \in G$ such that $g \not\in N_G(L)$.

Let $K = \langle P,g \rangle$. So $|K| = |P|q^t$, where $g$ has order $q^t$. Then $N_G(L)$ does not contain a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $K$, so $L$ is not S-permutable in $G$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr. Derek Holt.

Comment: If you agree with the proof, then you could consider upvoting and accepting the answer.